# Persist Pusher Event While navigating Pages in Web-Application

Tags: events, laravel-5, pusher

I am trying to build a real-time events firing with Laravel and Pusher. So far, I am able to reach the state where i am able to send events to Pusher Console and listen to the events on my web-page. But the problem is, events are not available on my application when a page is reloaded or refreshed. Every time a page is refreshed, Websocket try to reconnect itself which leads to loss of event while navigating from one page to another.
Is there any way to persist events while navigating pages ?

> Note: One way i found by looking for a solution is to go with "SPA" i.e Single Page Application but it's not feasible for my app.

So, what should i do to persist events in my Web-Pages ?

Answer (score 0):

Deciding on making your app a SPA only for this use case is probably not really acceptable to you. In this case you will have to store messages on your end, as Pusher does currently not offer message persistence. There are some blog posts and tutorials that could help you, [here's one](https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-add-message-history-to-your-pusher-apps/).

Comment: Will saving messages on our end affect real-time functionality ? @Haukur

Comment: @MAYANKBHATI In which way? You're going to have to fetch them separately, for one.